# What is the owner of UI elements of a view controller? iOS5 with ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I am new to iOS 5. From Apple's documentation I know what ARC is and "Owner of an object should using `strong` notation." After read  "Hello World" , I noticed a strange thing.(I mean that was confusing me)

HelloWorldAppDelegate:

```
@interface HelloWorldAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

HelloWorldViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HelloWorldViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender;

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *userName;
@end
```

Here:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

UI elements have `weak` notation and none of file have a `strong` references to them. So I am confusing `what/who hold them?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you can consider the NIB/XIB as the owner of those objects. None of your classes own them. See ["Managing the Lifetimes of Objects from Nib Files"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW6) in Resource Programming Guide:

> From a practical perspective, in iOS and OS X outlets should be defined as declared properties. **Outlets should generally be `weak`**, except for those from File's Owner to top-level objects in a nib file (or, in iOS, a storyboard scene) which should be `strong`. Outlets that you create should will therefore typically be weak by default, because:
>
> - Outlets that you create to, for example, subviews of a view controller's view or a window controller's window, are arbitrary references between objects that do not imply ownership.
> - The strong outlets are frequently specified by framework classes (for example, `UIViewController`'s `view` outlet, or `NSWindowController`'s `window` outlet).